# How to show all braodcast events of a particular app?

Tags: logging, intents, cell-broadcast

I know its possible to show all broadcast events/intents that are triggered in android. But I wanted to list all the broadcast events of a particular android app. My purpose is, I want to test a particular app for [broadcast theft](http://oasam.org/en/oasam/oasam-uir-unauthorized-intent-receipt/oasam-uir-001-broadcast-theft) vulnerabilities. It may be possible to reverse engineer the app and analyse the code. But its too time consuming. Is there any other methods to do this?

Is it possible with logcat? Can it be retrieved from the manifest file? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Dexplorer app on play store has the ability to read manifest file you can find all the intent there

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf It appears that not all the broadcasts receivers (and hence their intent filters) are mentioned in the manifest of an app. See [Registering BroadcastReceiver Programatically](http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/).

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. :( Is it necessary that I should reverse engineer?